# Boot fail - Asus EEE PC

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as my main operating system on my Asus EEE PC 1005HA machine.  When I restarted the pc, the boot loader didn't come up. I got only a black screen.

During the installation process, a Grub error asking to setup the initialization partition. I choose sda1 and continued, and then a got the no grub screen after restarting.

I reinstall again, (this time there was no error massage) but I still can't see the grub screen.

Is there a special config to install Ubuntu on Asus Netbook? It's to possible to fix my grub from the USB live CD?

Comment: Is the computer booting into Ubuntu?

Comment: After bios initial page, nothing is show, only a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you got set up the initialization partition, it maybe that you partition is not mounted.  Below are the steps to do so:

1. Boot your computer up with Ubuntu CD
2. Go through all the process until you reach "Disk Partition"
3. Select Manual Partition
4. Mount your appropriate Linux partitions

Comment: I fixed the bug with [Boot Repair][1]. Just run it and all was fixed.


  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Where the partitions mounted?

Comment: there just one partition, but when I updated grub, it ask me to select where to mount and show two options (my partition and one in usb flash disk). I think that in the first time I  mounted grub, it was on the usb flash disk. Even knowing that one of the options was the usb, I select all options to mount grub.